# Parenthesis sizing within macro

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I have a macro that typesets its arguments inside a set of parentheses `\left(...\right)`. For simplicity, let's say it's

```
\newcommand{\func}[1]{ \ensuremath{ f \left( #1 \right) } }
```

Sometimes, the automatically-determined parentheses are too small for my taste. For example,`func{\sin(x)}` produces

[image]

If I weren't using the macro, I know I could just do (e.g.)

```
f \bigl( \sin(x) \bigr)
```

and obtain

[image]

so that the nested parentheses are visually-distinct.

How can I implement this ability to manually adjust parenthesis sizing within a macro? Of course, I could just define `\funcbig`, `\funcBig` etc., but is there a way to define a single macro with this behaviour?

Comment: You might want to look at `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`. It seems to be becoming the de facto standard for such constructions (even if it is lacking some flexibility, in my opinion). Also, don’t wrap it all in `\ensuremath`. That will mess up stuff (or that is my impression at least).

Comment: @Gaussler `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` provide more flexibility, though I assume that's not the inflexibility you're referring to

Comment: @mbert I know about those. I consider them sub-species of the same command. And no, they still don’t provide enough flexibility with regard to e.g. adding decorations to the function symbol. For that, you still need to define separate commands. That’s why I made `semantex` (which, as far as I know, has exactly one active user, but he made it mainly for himself and hence doesn’t really care much ).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a definition of `\func` that employs the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` macro of the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package. The `\func` macro works as follows:

- `\func{x}` surrounds `x` with standard-size parentheses, i.e., is equivalent to `f(x)`
- `\func*{z}` surrounds `z` with auto-sized parentheses
- `\func[\big]{u}` surrounds `u` with `\big`-sized parentheses. In addition to `\big`, you can also state `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg` as the optional argument of `\func`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\func}[1]{f}{(}{)}{}{#1} % see p. 28 of user guide

\begin{document}
\[
\func{x} \quad 
\func*{\dfrac{\frac{a}{c}}{\frac{b}{d}}} \quad
\func[\bigg]{\,\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}\!}
\]
\end{document}
```